# Writing a template function for basic and Eigen data types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, eigen, eigen3

How can I write a function that takes both fundamental data types (int, float, double, …) and Eigen library types (Vector2f, Vector4d, Matrix4f, …)? Specifically, I want a cast function that casts the provided parameter to type N.

For example:

```
float x1 = cast<float>(1);
double x2 = cast<double>(2.0);
Vector2d x3 = cast<double>(Vector2f(3.0f, 3.0f));
Vector2f x4 = cast<float>(Vector2i(4, 4));
```

The easy part:

```
template<typename T, typename N>
N cast(const T& source) const
{
    return static_cast<N>(source);
}
```

Casting an Eigen type:

```
template<typename T, typename N>
Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_cast_op<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar, N>, const T> cast(const Eigen::MatrixBase<T>& source) const
{
    return source.cast<N>();
}
```

In Eigen, a cast from Vector2f *v* to Vector2d is done with `v.cast<double>()`, so the template parameter is the data type of the scalar, not the new type itself.

The trouble that I have (at least I think that's the main issue) is that I don't know how I can put these two templates together. The Eigen one should probably be a specialization of the first one, but is this even possible? The templates themselves compile, but e.g. `cast<Vector2f, double>(Vector2f::Zero())` will not, because *'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'const Eigen::Vector2f' to 'double'*.

What to do? C++11 solutions are very welcome, but please type slowly, as I am no template wizard.

**Update:**
The reason I need this is that I want to be able to conveniently cast the contents of containers, `std::vector<T>` to `std::vector<N>`, for example `std::vector<Vector2f>` to `std::vector<Vector2d>`, but also from `std::vector<float>` to `std::vector<double>`. For this, I loop over all elements and cast each one with the required function. So if there's a better way to cast a std::vector of Eigen types, this would be what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::enable_if` to limit the general version to arithmetic types only:

```
template<typename T, typename N>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,N>::type
cast(const T& source) const {
  return static_cast<N>(source);
}
```

Comment: That was a surprisingly easy solution! Thanks for the quick help! The N right before the function name should be removed, though.

Answer (score 1):

With C++17, there is another solution, which I personally find more elegant, using `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename T, typename N>
std::conditional<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, N, /* your Eigen return type here */>::type
cast( const T& source ) {
    if constexpr( std::is_arithmetic<T>::value )
        return static_cast<N>(source);
    else
        /* Eigen cast */
}
```

That way, it's all in one function, and I find the syntax a bit clearer.